# Dynamically generated form does not recognise different rows

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm building a dynamically generated table where every row is a form with some inputs and selects and has its own submit.

Here is my code so far:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      var princ = $('#principal').val();
      window.princ = princ;
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        url: 'post.php',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {"princ":princ},
        success: function (response) {
        alert("success");
        } }); }); });
</script>
                  <table id="assets_table">
                  <thead style=" cursor: pointer;">
                  <tr style="text-align: left; color: #fff;">
                       <th>Lender </th>
                       <th>Principal </th>
                       <th>Int. % </th>
                       <th>Term (mo.) </th>
                       <th>Collateral </th>
                       <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
 <?php
$competitions_id = $uscom['id'];
$users_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM competitions WHERE competition='$compe'");
$users_query_r = mysqli_fetch_array($users_query);
       foreach($users_query as $users_query_r) {
                   $usn = $users_query_r['Name'];
                    $usn_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE                        username='$usn'");
                      $usn_query_r = mysqli_fetch_array($usn_query);
                                                      ?>
<form>
<tr>
<td> <img src="<?= $punch_query_r['profile_pic'] ?>" alt="user"> <?= $users_query_r['Name'] ?></td>
<td><input id="principal" type="text" value="0" ></td>
<td><input id="rate" type="text" value="0" ></td>
<td><input id="term" class = "term_input" type="text" value="0" ></td>
<td><input id="collateral" type="text" value="0">
<select id="colselect" >
  <option selected disabled>Select asset</option>
 </select></td>
 <td> <input type="submit"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                   } ?>
                                                      </tbody>
                                                  </table>
</form>
```

However I cannot make it work properly because when I click on submit it does not really submit the corresponding row's form but the first one that was submitted.

I've also tried rewritting variables with input paste keyup but it does not solve the problem either because it just gets the last input whch was filled regardless of the row.

Any idea on how to solve it? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your open form tag comes after your tbody, but the form closes after the table close. Perhaps you should close the form before you close the tbody.

Comment: When you create something in PHP in the initial request, I don't consider it Dynamic (big D) as far a JavaScript goes.  I consider something that is rendered after the page load to be Dynamic.  ...  just saying.  You should create a table inside the larger table  or re-order you html, you cant put a form outside of a `<TD>` tag in a table.  `<table><form><tr><td></td></tr></form></table>`  should be `<form><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></form>`  and so on.  You can put the whole form (with it's table) inside a `td` of a parent table etc...  Things start getting messy though

Comment: Which is one of the reasons tables are no longer used as layout elements, more for data presentation then HTML structuring if that makes sense.

Comment: Mmmm, to be honest I can't still make it work. BTW you say tables are deprecated for this purpose. What's the alternative?